# Facebook status post error c# sdk

Tags: c#, facebook, post, sdk, status

I'm developing a facebook app, which I'm unexperianced with it. I wanted to post status from my page, but it posted just for once. Other posting trials didn't give any result. No compile-time or run-time errors, but no posts on my wall either. Here is my code.

```
fbClient.PostCompleted += (o, v) =>
        {
            if (v.Error == null)
            {
                var resultante = (IDictionary<string, object>)v.GetResultData();
                var newPostID = (string)resultante["id"];
            }
        };
        //dynamic parameters = new ExpandoObject();
        var parameters = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        parameters["message"] = txtWrite.Text;
        lbPosttoWall.Click += lbPosttoWall_Click;
        fbClient.Post("me/feed", parameters);
```